# stringWithFormat returning newline

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am adding objects to a mutable array by selecting choice(s) from my table view and viewing them in a text field. When I use stringWithFormat, the line of code is automatically adding in characters.

Example: I choose Bob from my table view

```
Bob
```

When I do a NSLog, it is actually appearing as

```
(
    Bob
)
```

But what is appearing in the text field is

```
(    Bob)
```

Because there is

```
(\n    Bob\n)
```

Here is the code that I am using to rid of the parentheses and replace commas with semicolons.

```
            // All Names is the mutable array I am adding information in. tableData is another mutable array with set names in them
            [AllNames addObject:tableData[0]];

            // If I chose the first option
            // NSString
            ourForces = [NSString stringWithFormat: AllNames[0]];

            // NSString
            combinedForces = [ourForces stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@";"];

            // NSString
            twoCombindForces = [combinedForces stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];

            // NSString
            UltmateCombinedForces = [twoCombindForces stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];

            //personnel is the text field
            personnel.text = UltmateCombinedForces;
```

Question now is : What is a less messy path to get

```
(    Bob)
```

to appear as

```
Bob
```

in my text field?

Solution update: After the following lines:

```
            // All Names is the mutable array I am adding information in. tableData is another mutable array with set names in them
            [AllNames addObject:tableData[0]];

            // If I chose the first option
            // NSString
            ourForces = [NSString stringWithFormat: AllNames[0]];
```

Include the following line of code:

```
personnel.text = [AllNames componentsJoinedByString:@";"];
```

That got rid of the (\n    Bob\n) extra characters that were showing up in the field. Thank you all for you help and wisdom. =)

Comment: What is Bob? What code are you using to log out Bob. What code are you using to create it? etc...

Comment: @Fogmeister,  "Bob" is just a name of a person I am displaying in a table view. tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Bob", nil];

Comment: textField? It can hold only 1 line of text. Use UILabel or UITextView.

Comment: OK, so what code are you using to log this into the console?

Comment: @Fogmeister, are you asking me what void method the lines of code are in?

Comment: You said "When I do NSLog it shows...". What is your code for "doing NSLog"?

Comment: My confusion is that if you create and array with a string `array = @[@"Bob"];` then log the entry in the array `NSLog(@"%@", array[0]);` there is no way that it will add brackets and new lines. So I'm trying to understand what exactly you are doing to get the brackets to appear.

Comment: NSLog(@"all table %@",AllNames); but this is just for me to know in the dos screen that the code is working

Comment: So, you're logging the array. Not the string itself. This is why you are seeing the brackets.

Comment: I think you need to clear up exactly what you are trying to do here. You are approaching this in the wrong way entirely. Manipulating the log of an array is something that you should **NEVER** do. What is it you are trying to achieve? i.e. something like "I have an array of names and I want to list all the names with commas in between" or "I'm trying to display the names in the cells of a table view"? etc...

Comment: Dude, you are confusing yourself. Step away from NSLog; that is not what the problem is. I am not trying to manipulate any log. I have an array of names and if I click on ANY of those names in the table view then I want them to appear in the field with semi-colons in between them. Example: "Bob; Joe; Sue; MaryAnn; etc"

Comment: You are manipulating the output string of an array. That's where **you** are confusing yourself. There are much easier ways of doing what you want and at the moment you are manipulating the log strong of an Array. The brackets and new lines etc... are from the `description` of that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`componentsJoinedByString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/componentsJoinedByString:) after filling the AllNames array:

```
personnel.text = [AllNames componentsJoinedByString:@";"];
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I understand what you're trying to do now.

You have an array of names...

```
NSArray *names = @[@"Bob", @"Sam", @"Dave"];
```

And you want a string of all these names...

```
@"Bob; Sam; Dave"
```

You seem to be separating them with a semi colon though? ; Is that correct?

You can do this with...

```
NSString *nameList = [names componentsJoinedByString:@"; "];
```

But I'm not entirely sure that this is what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Well, I have a table view with a list of people on there and whoever is out on the field has to fill out a form. There could be one person; there could be six people. When they choose the X amount of people in the table view, I want the chosen people to appear in a text field above. I am implementing it now. I will update my post once I am done in about five minutes.

Comment: I want to say thank you for your patience and help in my problem. I appreciate it a lot. Thank you. =)

Answer (score 0):

In NSLog the output expression

```
(
    Bob
)
```

represents an array. To get rid of the parentheses and newlines instead of

```
NSLog(@"%@", AllNames[0]);
```

write

```
NSLog(@"%@", AllNames[0][0]);
```

**… and please use variable names starting with a lowercase letter.**

Comment: You're absolutely correct about lower case variable names. Lower cases are efficient ways of programming. Thank you for the advice. =)

Answer (score -2):

You can use NSCharacter Set to remove items you don't want.. The below might offer a less messy solution.

```
   NSString *originalText = @"(    Bob) ";
    NSMutableCharacterSet *unwantedChars =  [NSMutableCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
    [unwantedChars addCharactersInString:@"()"];
    NSString *refinedText = [[originalText componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:unwantedChars] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Comment: I saw the whitespaceAndNewLineCharacterSet line of code on Google and decided to go a different route, but thank you for this new line of code. I will keep this in mind for future projects, thank you.